# Best method for storing customizable status flags, and writing customized queries based on said flags.

Tags: php, mysql, status

Right now, I have an app where theres a sales table.
So far Ive done fine with storing the status of a sale in an ENUM column type.
(APPROVAL, WAITING, PAID, INVOICED, COMPLETED)

However the client keeps wanting to add more statuses.
So I don't want to keep changing the ENUM column.

Id prefer that I just build them a customizable system, where they can create their own flags for rows.
And then the system, creates queries on the fly, based on these flags.

What would be the best method to do this?
Maybe this is too broad a question and not best for StackOverflow?

Comment: Yes - this is too broad. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried ENUM, thats all I have.  But Im asking how to best do it, to make it customizable by the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method is to have a reference table for the statuses.  You would store the status id in the `sales` table, and have a foreign key relationship to the status table.

You can then add new statuses quite easily and the rest of the system will just work.  You can also rename an existing status, with equal ease.

Comment: Yeah this was my first intuition on the problem.  Thanks.  I think Ill use it.